# Change to protocol and the server name in IIS rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <!-- https://localhost/bbb/aaa/something -->
            <rule name="rule_name" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="aaa/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="aaa/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

How do I configure (from web.config) this rule to **rewrite** the URL to:

```
http://localhost/aaa/something
```

---

The following does not work:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/aaa/{R:1}" />
```

Comment: you cannot rewrite https to http (or visa versa), but you can redirect.

Comment: with a redirect, the client will know I forward the request to someone else. even if its still in localhost

Comment: Rewriting https to http (or another way) just doesn't make sense, so you will have to use another way.

Comment: Another way might be using reverse proxy. I don't work with IIS for years, but maybe this article will help: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Comment: @Evk multiple services arre located at the same machine and only one of them is the entry point. from there, the client can reach the rest of the services. So there is no need for the rest of the services to communicate with https because they are not exposed.

Comment: Did you read the article above? I'm not sure but I think that's what you need.

Comment: Just started! looks interstring! Thanks!